# When should I use "finish" instead of "complete," and vice versa?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I am confused about when to use *finish* instead of *complete* and vice versa.

May you help me in understanding when to use those words?

Comment: You asked about "finish" and "complete"? I didn't get it... Editing my answer. :D

Comment: When you marry the right woman, you are *complete*. And when you marry the wrong woman, you are *finished*. And when the right one catches you with the wrong one, you are *completely finished*! -Samsundar Balgobin, recent London linguistic competition ftw!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are kind of synonyms but not really interchangeable.

**To finish** means simply bringing something (a task or activity) to an end, or simply stop doing it:

> *We finished eating our meal.*
>   <sub>(In this case you *wouldn't* use complete: "*We completed eating our meal.*" is not the preferred usage).</sub>

**To complete** means finish making or doing, such as in:

> *He completed his Ph.D. in 1983.*

But another meaning peculiar to "complete" is making something whole or perfect, or with the meaning of "filling a form"::

> - *He only needed one thing to complete his happiness.*
> - *Please complete the attached forms.*

While *to finish* means merely bringing something to an end, or stop doing that something, *to complete* has the acception of fulfilling something.

Lastly, I'll leave you with this I found on the net:

> "*When you marry the right person, you're complete. When you marry the wrong one, you're finished.*"

Comment: @Peter: :D It's very explicative!

Comment: The last quote was the killer part. Nice :) +1

Comment: And, when the right woman catches you with the wrong women, you are 'Completely Finished' :)

Answer (score 4):

When you finished your life, it does not mean it is complete; when you have completed your life, it is finished!

Comment: Yes, easy to understand. You can finish  a task at anytime. But you only can complete the task once at the end.